# Is it possible to use `df` when some of the NFS disks are unresponsive?

Tags: disk-usage, nfs, hang

I have some Ubuntu file server that is connected to several NFS disks. Due to some earthquake, some NFS disks became unresponsive. This results in  the  `df` command hanging forever. Is it possible to use `df` when some of the NFS disks are unresponsive? E.g., by specifying some timeout (such as: "if disk x doesn't respond within y second, skip").

Comment: I’m not sure this is what you’re looking for, but `df -x nfs` will list all non-NFS file systems (or `-x nfs4` if you’re using v4).

Comment: Also consider switching to automounts so that if/when mounts are unavailable, they will unmount in the background.

Comment: @StephenKitt I want `df` or something else to list all the mounted disks and indicate available/used space for each of them. If some disks are unresponsive, then it should state so or at worse, skip it.

Comment: I find the following alias useful: `alias dflocal='df -x nfs4  -x cifs'`.     Actually, the version I use also has `-x tmpfs -x devtmpfs` because most of the time I'm not interested in /run, /dev, /dev/shm, /run/lock or other tmpfs mounts.   if I used other kinds of network filesystems, I'd add them to the alias too.

Comment: Thanks, `df -x nfs4` and `df -x nfs`  also hang forever. Also, I had a few other mounted NFS that are responsive and that I would like to see in the list returned by `df`.

Comment: `mount` will list mounted filesystems. `df` with a single argument shows only that fs. GNU's `timeout` gives you a timeout. i expect that the three could be combined in order to achieve your goal

Comment: @Fox thanks `timeout` will time out the entire `df`. Instead I want df or something else to list all the mounted disks and indicate available/used space for each of them. If some disks are unresponsive, then it should state so or at worse, skip it.

Comment: right. i'm suggesting something along the lines of a shell loop, iterating over the list of filesystems produced by `mount`, doing one `df` call per fs with a timeout attached. i'm not in a place to set up a test, nor am i even sure it would work since the `-x nfs` flag isn't enough to prevent the hang, but it might be worth looking into?

Comment: @Fox got it, thanks for the idea!